# Why are my environment variables not detected when starting up celery?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, daemon

I am running django on centos served by apache and mod_wsgi. I followed the instructions to set up celery to be run as a daemon.

I put this init script https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd in `/etc/init.d/celeryd`

and set up the configuration in

```
/etc/default/celeryd
```

I am using environment variables in my django settings.py file so I can use different configurations in my development and production environments. I know these environment variables are set correctly because the app has been working this whole time. I think that celery is just not getting the variable passed to it or something.

I checked by typing the `env` command. variables are showing fine.

To start up I just do:

```
service celeryd start
```

It tries to start up but throws an error saying that I do not have my environment variables set.

I wrote a function to grab environment variables. that is what throws the error.

```
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

The only way that error is thrown is if the environment variable is not set correctly.

Does anyone know why celery is not detecting the enironment variables that I have set?

Answer (score 13):

I just discovered that I not only had to set my environment variables in the system, but I also had to pass those variables in to the /etc/default/celleryd script.

I just put my variables at the bottom of /etc/default/celleryd:

```
export MY_SPECIAL_VARIABLE = "my production variable"
export MY_OTHERSPECIAL_VARIABLE = "my other production variable"
```

Comment: This, however does not work with the $PATH variable, which is apparently reset after the /etc/init.d/celeryd calls celery

Comment: If your environment variable are defined in virtualenv postactivate, you can add a new line `. /{{ path_to_your_virtualenv_bin }}/postactivate` to the bottom of `/etc/default/celeryd`

Answer (score 2):

if environment variables write on `~/.bashrc`, you can add `source ~/.bashrc` to `/etc/init.d/celeryd` at first.

Answer (score 1):

Does your `/etc/default/celeryd` define what user celery should run as?

In mine I have:

```
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

Can you post your `/etc/defaults/celeryd` config file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did have the user and the group set after creating the celery user. Just figured it out though and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using celery and supervisor, I had supervisord to use a shell script to start celery worker and also source the env variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.profile
CELERY_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log
CELERYD_OPTS=" --loglevel=INFO --autoscale=10,5 --concurrency=8"
cd /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/conf
exec celery worker -n celeryd@%h -f $CELERY_LOGFILE $CELERYD_OPTS
```

in ~/.profile:

```
export C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
export KEY="DEADBEEF"
```